# How do I stop my terminal from clearing the command when I hit enter

Tags: bash, terminal, tty, cygwin

I am using mintty under Cygwin on Windows 10.  I don't know why this started happening but suddenly everytime I type a command and hit enter, the command and all the scrollback text is cleared. I don't know what I could have done to cause this.  Does anyone know how to get out of this mode.  It persists when I logout/login. It does not happen with a regular Cygwin bash shell and a regular DOS Commmand terminal is fine.  It also happens when using vi which is the most annoying.

Comment: Show us: this is a good time for a picture.

Comment: Unfortunately this computer is on a private network with no Internet connectivity.

Comment: I often tell people off for using photo, when they could create a screen/window grab, and for posting screen grabs, when they could post text, but I think this time a photo is OK.

Comment: I have checked the prompt (PS1), it's using eval export PS1=\"`basename \"$PWD\"`: \" . Nothing in the .profile.  I have also tried not setting it at all but didn't help.

Comment: It may be related to a Macafee update.

Comment: @JohninMD did you figure this out?  I too am having the same exact issue since yesterday and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Still trying to figure it out but it began happening when a Mcafee update happened.

Comment: If you do figure this out please post the resolution here as I'm still having this issue.  I noticed that backspace also does not work anymore either.  I'm not sure if that is your case too.

Comment: I figured out that using control-m (sending CR only) seems to work fine, i.e., executes the command and does not clear the screen.